# Oracle PLSQL: xmltype.transform vs xmltransform

Tags: sql, xslt, plsql, transform, oracle11gr2

Since we have moved the database from 11.2.0.2.0 to 11.2.0.4.0 `xmltype.transform` function had got a specific behaviour.

The problem is that before it did not work fine: it replaced all tags with open-close version (e.g. it did replace `<br />` with `<br></br>`), but I could live with it. Now it behaves the other way round (replaces everything with one tag) and it makes a big problem with `<script></script>` tag, because this tag **must** be explicitly closed with a `</script>` otherwise the browser thinks it is not closed, even if it is closed so `<script />` => all web pages are corrupted now.

Example:

```
declare
  xml      xmltype := new xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><document></document>');
  xsl      xmltype := new xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
                                   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                                     <xsl:output method="html" />
                                     <xsl:template match="/">
                                       <html>
                                         <head>
                                           <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
                                         </head>
                                         <body>
                                           <br />
                                         </body>
                                       </html>
                                     </xsl:template>
                                   </xsl:stylesheet>');
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(xml.transform(xsl,null).getclobval());
end;
```

In 11.2.0.2.0 this works like this:

```
<html><head><script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script></head><body><br></br></body></html>
```

In 11.2.0.4.0 it works different:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I guess the problem is in formatting, but I did not set up anything else to enable it...

What is interesting, I've found [this article](http://mikepargeter.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/xmltype-transform-in-oracle11g/) with another problem, but with the same workaround as a solution:

```
select xmltransform(xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><document></document>'),
                    xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
                             <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                               <xsl:output method="html" />
                               <xsl:template match="/">
                                 <html>
                                   <head>
                                     <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
                                   </head>
                                   <body>
                                     <br />
                                   </body>
                                 </html>
                               </xsl:template>
                             </xsl:stylesheet>')) html
from dual
```

this just works in every version and gives a proper result (the one with doubled `<br />`, but as I've said, it does not matter to me).

In Oracle documentation there is nothing said about the difference in these functions; they even say many times that they are the same functions ([see here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb08tra.htm#ADXDB0900)).

I will, of course, use this workaround, but, please, tell me: is it possible to make it work again without changing the code?

What is the reason of this behaviour?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry for maybe an annoying question, but ...
Shouldn't the `<xsl:template-match>` node contain things like `&lt;html&gt;`, `&lt;script src=&quot;...&quot;&gt;`, ... instead of `<html>`, `<script src="...">`, ... ? I suspect that the contents of the XSL template are your troublemaker, not the changed behaviour of the XSL-transform engine.

Comment: `&lt;html&gt;` is going to be displayed in the browser as string `<html>` and not interpreted as a tag. This is absolutely not correct. Have you seen any example where your idea works at all? See [w3c example](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex1), they have exactly the same structure. And if your idea is right, why did my XSLT work before, and why does it work with just another function?

Comment: Sorry, Simon, I have no idea why it worked before and does not work now. I'm sorry if I upset you in any way. I was just "thinking aloud" ... I see that you send your XSLT as a string into the xmltype() constructor, which clearly parses also the contents of the <xsl:template> node as another XML sub-nodes. That's why I suggested that you at least tried to html-escape the contents of the <xsl:template>. If I were absolutely sure that I'm right, I would write a regular answer to your question. But I'm not sure at all, I just posted an idea as a comment.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Sorry for a bit rude words...

Comment: Both scenarios work fine in 11.2.0.3.0.  probably does not help you much but might narrow it down to something happening between .3 and .4...

Comment: Also, it seems that `xmltype.transform()` works the same way (tried on 12.1.0.1) when `<xsl:output method="xml" />` is used instead of `"html"`.

Comment: so, could be possible that it treats this directive `<xsl:output method="html" />` as `xml` in a problematic case?

Comment: I can only guess, but it certainly seems so.