# Oracle PLSQL:Oracle 12c 11g XMLType.transform differences

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

`XMLType.transform` is outputting different HTML tags on Oracle 12c versus Oracle 11g.

11g:

```
<td align="right"></td>
<td></td>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return false;" checked="checked"/>Yes</td>
```

12c :

```
<td align="right"/>
<td/>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return false;" checked="checked"/>Yes</td>
```

Unfortunately, the results are stored and hashed, which is completely broken by these minor changes.

This is the stylesheet's heading.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes' omit-xml-declaration='yes' />
```

This question is similar [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486716/oracle-plsql-xmltype-transform-vs-xmltransform)

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes' omit-xml-declaration='yes' />